# Is there a way to install jupyter without installing Qt?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way to install jupyter without installing Qt?

I dont use qtconsole, would like to remove pyQt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't install `qtconsole`.

With **conda**, do `conda install notebook` or `conda install jupyterlab`. Don't run `conda install jupyter`, as this will install `qtconsole` (look at the [conda-forge recipe](https://github.com/conda-forge/jupyter-feedstock/blob/master/recipe/meta.yaml)).

With **pip**, do `pip install notebook` or `pip install jupyterlab`. Don't run `pip install jupyter`, as this will install `qtconsole` (look at the [jupyter setup.py](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/blob/master/setup.py)).